# Migrating Data accross different DB Schema

Tags: java

I want to migrate my data from one DB to other using Java. Both DBs have different schema structure. I might also need to define some mapping / validation rule. Can anyone please guide me about any strategy, framework or any opensource project.

Thanks

---

Isn't in this case I have to create all the POJO to match the both schema (even by auto generating). Is there any way to avoid this thing i.e. giving schema mapping and generating POJO on fly in memory ?

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need an Extract-Transform-Load (ETL) tool.

Here are some open source choices:

http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=open+source+etl

Answer (score 0):

ETL is generally used for this as in duffymo's answer.. you could also try ORM tools for this:

There is the Torque project.. http://db.apache.org/torque/

Read the data from your existing schema into java objects, then set them into the other objects for the other schema and then save them into the database. I am pretty sure hibernate also can be used, although I havent used hibernate per se. It works on the same way as torque..